# Rails form isn't being submitted, nothing is logged

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with a Rails form for user registration. When the button is clicked, nothing happens. Nothing is logged in the console, nothing is created and the page remains the same. Here's the view users/new.html.erb:

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "User name" %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
          <%= f.submit "Create an account" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

And here is the controller.

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        redirect_to '/register'
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
end
```

I've got the following route set up:

```
resources :users
get 'register' => 'users#new'
```

And finally my user migration (the model has has_secure_password)

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not logging anything in the failure case (the `else` in your `create` action), and you're redirecting instead of rendering so you'll be getting a new `@user` each time rather than displaying the existing `@user` with any errors it may contain.

Change your `else` to:

```
else
  logger.debug @user.errors.full_messages
  render :new
end
```

I'm not sure if you **do** have any error handling code in your `new` view, but even if you don't the above will at least log the errors for you.